# IBDesignable rendered at the top left of the screen instead of their correct position

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable, layoutsubviews

I have a custom implementation of a checkbox / radio button in Swift.
The class is annotated as `@IBDesignable`. I implement `layoutSubviews` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`.

This implementation is distributed in a pod that is used in several applications. I know that Cocoapods has caused and is still causing some inconsistencies in the IB behavior, but I don't believe that it is part of the issue here.

Everything is fine when I run the application. However, when I use the interface builder, the box is always rendered on the top left of the parent view instead of being in its own view.

How can I fix this? Is my implementation of `layoutSubviews` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` relevant?

EDIT: I made a sample project here: https://github.com/csarkis/TestIBDesignablesPod/

Just run `pod install` and open the project.

Here is a simplified rendition of the designable view:

```swift
class RadioButton: UIControl {
    /// Radio button radius
    private var radioButtonSize: CGFloat = 20

    /// A Boolean value that determines the off/on state of the radio button. Default is on
    @IBInspectable public var isOn: Bool = true { ... }

    ...

    // MARK: Initialisers
    /// :nodoc:
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    /// :nodoc:
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }

    /// Setup the view initially
    private func setupViews() {
        self.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.autoresizesSubviews = false

        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    /// Main color of the radio button element
    private var color: UIColor { ... }

    // MARK: View management
    // MARK: Custom drawings
    /// Width of the unchecked radio circle
    private var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2

    /// :nodoc:
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setStrokeColor(self.color.cgColor)
        context.setFillColor(self.color.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(self.borderWidth)

        drawRadio(in: rect, for: context)
    }

    private func drawRadio(in rect: CGRect, for context: CGContext) {
        // Radio button
        // Draw inside the box, considering the border width
        let newRect = rect.insetBy(dx: (rect.width - radioButtonSize + borderWidth) / 2,
                                   dy: (rect.height - radioButtonSize + borderWidth) / 2)

        // Draw the outlined circle
        let borderCircle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newRect)
        borderCircle.stroke()
        context.addPath(borderCircle.cgPath)
        context.strokePath()
        context.fillPath()

        ...
    }

    /// :nodoc:
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    /// :nodoc:
    public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    }

    /// :nodoc:
    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    ...
}
```

My observation on this simple pod is that the behavior is very inconsistant (a lot of crashes and random errors). Here, the checkbox is first rendered on the top left and moves to its correct position as soon as we modify any attribute. The class is [RadioButton.swift](https://github.com/csarkis/TestIBDesignablesPod/blob/master/GraphicLibrary/RadioButton.swift).

Comment: You probably need to post the complete class... I just added simple `drawRadio` and `drawCheckbox` funds, and quick testing does ***not*** show the problem you're describing.

Comment: I added a sample project with the class RadioButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`: A view (esp a designable one) should never set its own value for this property.

Interface Builder (or the view controller, if doing it programmatically) is responsible for configuring this. A view can set `translatesAutoresizingMask` and constraints for its subviews (if it had any, which you do not in this case) if it is using auto layout for subviews, but a view should never set its own `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` (nor add its own width/height constraints).

See https://github.com/csarkis/TestIBDesignablesPod/pull/1.

---

A few other suggestions:

1. Your `draw(_:)` is using supplied `CGRect` to determine the size and placement of the radio button.

   Do not do that. Always use `bounds` for computing where things go, not the supplied `rect` parameter. As the documentation says, the rect is

   > The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire visible bounds of your view. However, during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view.

   So, in complicated views, we might use `rect` to determine *what* is drawn (e.g. if `rect` doesn't intersect with what you're drawing, you do not need to draw it). But never use `rect` to determine *where* it is drawn. Use `bounds`.
2. In a more radical edit, you have a `setupViews` for your `@IBDesignable` view:

   ```swift
   /// Setup the view initially
   private func setupViews() {
       self.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.autoresizesSubviews = false

       self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
       self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

       prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
       setNeedsDisplay()
   }
   ```

   You should not be doing *any* of that in this designable view:

   - You have no subviews, so iterating through and deleting all subviews is unnecessary (and that is an extremely imprudent practice, btw, as you do not know what subviews someone else may have added). Nor is `autoresizesSubviews` necessary.
   - As described above, a view (esp a designable one) should never set its own `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. That is the job of whatever added the view to the view hierarchy (IB in this case). Nor should you set the constraints.
   - You are calling `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` and `setNeedsDisplay` here. Neither is needed nor desired.

   Now that you no longer have `setupSubviews`, a whole bunch of other observers and overrides are now no longer necessary, greatly simplifying the code. See https://github.com/csarkis/TestIBDesignablesPod/pull/2.

Comment: Hi @Rob,
Thanks for your suggestions. I will accept your second PR and keep the project on GH, as other people may want to have this implementation for a checkbox or a radio button.
My full implementation has indeed subviews. This is why many unneeded overrides were still there in the sample. Thank you for your time and science anyway!